# Retrieve data from database and bulk index them - Sql Server

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have some records in SQL Server management studio and I want to index them to my ES index.
At present I'm indexing them individually which is taking a long time. I would like to bulk index them. I tried using the Bulk Descriptor it is throwing an error saying > the object to index, if id not set manually it will be inferred from the object

below is my code.

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString();
                using (cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbName"];
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = cn;

                    cn.Open();

                    //to index the students response into the ES 
                    try
                    {
                        client = ConfigSettings.connection();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                        throw;
                    }

                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();
                            descriptor.Index<Class1>(b=>b.Document(new Class1
                            {
                                Id = Int32.Parse(reader[0].ToString()),
                                Title = reader[1].ToString(),
                                BodyContent = reader[2].ToString()  
                            }, z => z.Refresh()));
                        }

Client.Bulk(descriptor);
```

**Client settings**

```
        configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"];
        var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(configvalue1));
        var defaultIndex = "dbtrial";

        settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
         .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
         .MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(Class1), "records"))

        client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        client.createIndex(defaultIndex);
```

Is there any way other than descriptor to index thousands of documents in a efficient way?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Take a look at some of the settings int https://www.elastic.co/blog/performance-considerations-elasticsearch-indexing and https://www.elastic.co/blog/performance-indexing-2-0. Measure scientifically to find the sweet spot for the size of bulk requests to send for your documents, hardware and environment

Comment: Thanks Russ Cam. But before checking for alternate methods, is my code correct? because When i use my code, it is throwing an error near the Descriptor part. TIA

Comment: You should send bulk requests in batches of documents. How many documents to send in each bulk request is going to depend on the document structure, hardware and environment, so you will need to find the optimum bulk size for your scenario through experimentation. I'd be inclined to paginate records from the database and send a bulk request per page

Comment: @RussCam Thanks for the information. Will try using batches of documents..I would like to know about how does the performance differ from using IndexMany and Bulk method(as suggested above) and where will the difference come between those two? Because i used IndexMany(as below code) and able to index documents. So just curious to know the difference. TIA :)

Comment: `IndexMany()` is just a short convenience method for `Bulk()` with a `BulkIndexOperation` for each document - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/2.x/src/Nest/Document/Multiple/Bulk/ElasticClient-IndexMany.cs#L23

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this and it is working fine for indexing(it is taking between 3300ms to 4500ms for indexing 1000 documents.So I'm not sure if this can be reduced further using any other method). I'm not sure of the performance if there are some millions of records.

```
List<Class1> feedlist = new List<Class1>();                        

                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            class1 c = new Class1
                            {
                                Id = Int32.Parse(reader[0].ToString()),
                                Title = reader[1].ToString(),
                                BodyContent = reader[2].ToString()  
                            };
                            feedlist.Add(c);
                        }
client.IndexMany(feedlist, "dbtrial", "records");
```

Any better methods for indexing millions on records can be suggested. 
TIA